# Creating a migration for building a table whose columns are derived from rows of another table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, pivot

Is there a way (other than manually typing a migration) to create a new table in Rails where the column names are derived from the column values of another table?  This will be a wide table (~100 columns) so I'd really like to avoid doing this manually.

Existing table looks like this:

```
 -----------
| nameCol |
-----------
| A       |
| A       |
| B       |
| C       |
-----------
```

I want to create another table that looks like this:

```
| pk | A | B | C |
```

Presently working with sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would run a query using group_concat like -

```
select group_concat(distinct namecol) as namecols
from tbl
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/57f05/3/0

Then bring the results into Excel and use text to columns:

[image]

Use comma as the delimitter.

Then write a formula underneath the first column name (between a create table statement) like so:

[image]

Copy the formula down to the last column. Remove the comma from the formula in that last cell since it is the last column in the list. Copy the cells from left to right representing the create table statement, and use that to create the table.

Example excel file, link valid for 2 days:

example.xlsx:
http://shwivel.synology.me:5000/fbsharing/xE336ePi
Expiration date: 2014-08-04